# How to bind a property of an ItemsPanel to a property of the parent

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have a custom panel that has a public dependency property **MaxItemsCount**(defines the maximum number of elements in the panel), and I am giving this panel as an ItemsPanel to my custom control.

```
<Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <myPrimitives:MyPanel MaxItemsCount="5"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I also have a public dependency property **in my custom control** called **MaxItemsCount** as well.

**Is there a way to bind the MaxItemsCount of my panel to the MaxItemsCount of my custom control.**

I tried doing the following:

```
<Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <myPrimitives:MyPanel MaxItemsCount="{TemplateBinding MaxItemsCount}"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

...but apparently it's not how it's done.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your custom control is called MyControl, you could do it like that :

```
<myPrimitives:MyPanel MaxItemsCount="{Binding MaxItemsCount, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type myPrimitives:MyControl}}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but the solution you are providing is for WPF only.
After some digging, I came to the conclusion that the only way this to happen is via the code-behind.